# Removing undefined values from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

In certain situations, it may happen that we have `undefined` or generally *falsy* values in Array structures. For instance when reading and filling data from some unknown sources like Databases or HTML structures. Like

```
var data = [42, 21, undefined, 50, 40, undefined, 9]
```

Since that might cause trouble when looping over such arrays and working on the elements, what is the best practice to remove `undefined` (falsy values) ?

Comment: How about this http://jsfiddle.net/5uuyoo5t/ ?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

To use `Array.prototype.filter` here might be obvious. So to remove only undefined values we could call

```
var data = [42, 21, undefined, 50, 40, undefined, 9];

data = data.filter(function( element ) {
   return element !== undefined;
});
```

If we want to filter out all the falsy values (such as 0 or null) we can use `return !!element;` instead.

But we can do it slighty more elegant, by just passing the `Boolean` constructor function, respectively the `Number` constructor function to `.filter`:

```
data = data.filter( Number );
```

That would do the job in this instance, to generally remove any *falsy* value, we would call

```
data = data.filter( Boolean );
```

---

Since the `Boolean()` constructor returns `true` on *truthy* values and `false` on any *falsy* value, this is a very neat option.

Comment: Just note that `filter(Number)` will also remove `0`.

Comment: this will also remove falsey values like `false`, which may exist in the array

Comment: @jAndy Thanks. It solved my problem in IE 11 as well. Earlier I used arrow function to remove undefined.

Comment: This can be shortened to `.filter(n=>n!==undefined)`

Comment: If you just said "...damn..." under your breath then you're officially a nerd like me! 

Comment: Someone might get confused, so : The callback function receives the element, that means that doing `filter(Boolean)` is the same as `filter((elem)=>Boolean(elem)`.

Comment: Does it also work with Interface? Custom types? in TypeScript? I tried but failed :(

Comment: Please, remove null/undefined values from such array: ```
a = [];
a[0] = "UK";
a[1] = 7;
a["5"] = 8;
a["32"] = 77;
a[7] = 0;
a["8"] = NaN;
a[9] = undefined;
a["10"] = null;
a[11] = {};
a["19"] = false;
a[20] = true;
a[40] = 'wonderland';
a[41] = 98;
a[4294967294] = 42;
```

Answer (score 140):

Inline using lambda

```
result.filter(item => item);
```

Comment: this one will remove all falsey values.  Since the OP specified falsey values being unwanted, this is definitely the best answer IMO.  However, thy also specifically point out undefined at which point you'd want `result.filter(item => item !== undefined)`

Comment: `[true,false,undefined,null,'a',1,0,'0'].filter(x=>x)` returns `[true, "a", 1, "0"]`

Comment: best answer here

Comment: JS newby here.  People say this is the best answer but why is this better than `filter(Boolean)` or `filter(item => !!item)`

Comment: @AdamHughes It's not, ppl often overvalue brevity compared to clarity. Of the 3, `filter(item => !!item)` would actually be the best bc it clearly communicates that you're filtering on the truthiness of item. `Boolean` would be the worst bc both the input and operation are no longer explicit. Plus it looks like you're filtering for booleans, which is definitely not what it does.

Answer (score 32):

You can use lodash `compact` method, which removes `null`, `undefined` and `''`.

```
_.compact(data)
```

Comment: that's not freely available without another library. That's overkill

Comment: This works and cleans the array. this is the solution i prefer

Answer (score 29):

```
[NaN, undefined, null, 0, 1, 2, 2000, Infinity].filter(Boolean)
//[ 1, 2, 2000, Infinity ]
```

Answer (score 24):

If you have an array of objects and want to remove all `null` and `undefined` items:

```
[].filter(item => !!item);
```

Answer (score 22):

ES6 single line

```
data.filter(e => e)
```

Comment: Careful, this also removes any "falsey" values, like zero. `[undefined, null, 0, false].filter(e => e) // []`

Comment: JavaScript is weird at times :D

Comment: This is best for array of objects

Answer (score 20):

```js
data.filter(Boolean)
```

Is the most short and readable way to do it.

Comment: Why does this work? Don't just post "magic" explain also how it works and why this is a good solution.

Comment: @LucianEnache it applies Boolean function for every item of the array and if it converts to false, it filters it out. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: Why is the resulting array, still typed as potentially containing undefined?

Comment: @SeanMC It's another question, concerning typescript. It doesn't play well with array.filter. You can find additional info on this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010737/way-to-tell-typescript-compiler-array-prototype-filter-removes-certain-types-fro

Comment: The most short way to say most short is shortest. It's also the readablest way.

Answer (score 7):

As Diogo Capela said, but where 0 is not filtered out as well.

```
[].filter(item => item !== undefined && item !== null)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var a =  ["3","", "6"];
var b =  [23,54,56];
var result = [];

for (var i=0;i<a.length;++i) {
    if (a[i] != "") {
        result[i] = b[i];
    }
}

result = result.filter(function( element ) {
   return element !== undefined;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var arr1 = [NaN, 0, 15, false, -22, '',undefined, 47, null];

var array1 = arr1.filter(function(e){ return e;});

document.write(array1);
```

*single lined answer*

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.reduce()` can be used to delete elements by condition from an array but with additional transformation of the elements if required in one iteration.

---

Remove `undefined` values from array, with sub-arrays support.

```
function transform(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((memo, item) => {
        if (typeof item !== "undefined") {
            if (Array.isArray(item)) item = transform(item);
            // We can transform item here.
            memo.push(item);
        }
        return memo;
    }, []);
}

let test1 = [1, 2, "b", 0, {}, "", , " ", NaN, 3, undefined, null, 5, false, true, [1, true, 2, , undefined, 3, false, ''], 10];

console.log(transform(test1));
```

---

Try it on [jsfiddle.net/bjoy4bcc/](https://jsfiddle.net/bjoy4bcc/)

Answer (score 2):

in ES6 this can be achieved by simply using using filter  with function return the value like this:

```js
const array = [NaN, 0, 15, false, -22, '',undefined, 47, null];
const filteredArr = array.filter(elm => elm);
console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution with `Array.filter` will actually keep the array unchanged and create a new array without the undesired items. If you want to clean an array without duplicating it, you can use this:

```
for (var i = data.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!data[i]) {
        data.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Typescript and want to return an Array of strings vs from Array<string|undefined> try one of these...

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', undefined, 'e', undefined, 'g'];
var solutionA = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    item && acc.push(item);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log('solution a', solutionA);

var solutionB = [];
arr.forEach((each) => each && solutionB.push(each), []);

console.log('solution b', solutionB);

arr.forEach((each,index) => (!each) && arr.splice(index,1),[]);
console.log('solution c', arr);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
var data = Object.keys(data)
```

This will remove undefined values but array index will change

Comment: Was there supposed to be more code here? All this is going to do is return an array of the numbers 0-6.