# Way to tell TypeScript compiler Array.prototype.filter removes certain types from an array?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to filter null (undefined) element from an array by using Array.prototype.filter but TypeScript compiler does not seem to recognize the derived array of the "filter" function and failed to pass type check.

Assuming following simplified code where I have an array with (number|undefined)[] types and want to filter undefined to fit into a number[] array.

```
const arry = [1, 2, 3, 4, "5", 6];
const numArry: number[] = arry
    .map((i) => {
        return typeof i === "number" ? i : void 0;
    })
    .filter((i) => i);
```

Error says:

> Type '(number | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
>    Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
>      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

I can cast the resulted array to number[] like below knowing filter function removes undefined.

```
const arry = [1, 2, 3, 4, "5", 6];
const numArry: number[] = (arry
    .map((i) => {
        return typeof i === "number" ? i : void 0;
    })
    .filter((i) => i) as Number[]);
```

Is there a better way to achieve this other than casting?

Environment: TSC2.1 with strictNullChecks enabled.

Comment: What version of typescript are you on? Your initial code works just fine for me with no modifications on TS 2.0.9

Comment: This question assumes --strictNullChecks

Comment: This problem is partially related to [how type guards aren't currently propagated on filters over Arrays, but instead only ReadonlyArrays](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10916).

Comment: Thanks @artem is right. Forgot to mention but using tsc 2.1 with strictNullChecks enabled.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Use User-Defined Type Guards feature of TypeScript:

```
const arry = [1, 2, 3, 4, "5", 6];
const numArry: number[] = arry
    .filter((i): i is number => {
        return typeof i === "number";
    });
// numArry = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Take a look at `i is number` in the callback function.
This trick gives us ability to cast a type of the Array.filter result.

Comment: Looking for commentary from the community...  [this TS bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7657) indicates that this has been fixed, but to my eye this type guard smells like a hack.  What gives?

Comment: Static analysis has its limits. If there is code between declaration and type check, it is difficult to know what will be in the array at runtime without running the code.

Comment: This is a force cast and it's dangerous. The logic checking for the type is not validated anyhow so it could be wrong and it's not going to error out even when the type we cast to changes.

Answer (score 100):

**Solution**

Create a *type guard*:

```
function isDefined<T>(argument: T | undefined): argument is T {
    return argument !== undefined
}
```

Use it as your type predicate:

```
const foo: number[] = [1, 2, undefined, 4].filter(isDefined)
```

**Explanation**

`Array.prototype.filter` has a few overloads. One of them understands that the return value will depend on your predicate function. It uses a type guard:

```
filter<S extends T>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[];
```

Using a proper type guard (instead of taking a shortcut and relying on implicit coercion) helps TypeScript pick this specific overload.

Answer (score 25):

The easiest way to filter values from an array in a typesafe way that Typescript understands is to use `flatMap` instead of `map` and return an empty array for anything you want to remove.

Example:

```
const myArray = [1,2,3,4,"5",6,7, undefined,9, 0]
const filteredArray = arr.flatMap(val => typeof val === "number" ? val : [])
// filteredArray: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 0 ]
```

`flatMap` works in two steps. First it maps over the array and executes any function you've given it. Then it flattens any arrays in it.

1. map over the array and get:
   `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, [], 6, 7, [], 9, 0 ]`
2. Flatten any arrays in the array:
   `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 0 ]`

Voila! Now you have a typed array and Typescript is happy.

[image]

Comment: That's hacky but brilliant

Comment: I would say it is ill-advised to change the way your code works from a stack/heap/CPU standpoint to make compile time IntelliSense happy.

Comment: @boylec1986 is it erroneous in some way? As I see it, it's correct both from a pure data point of view, as well as from a type checking point of view.

Comment: It is definitely correct from a data and type checking standpoint but it is sub-optimal from a mechanical standpoint. You're performing extraneous operations that consume CPU cycles and memory on the client that is consuming the code (a map plus a flat map) in order to get the type checking to be happy. So yes the compiler is happy, but at the expense of code quality.

There is no telling how big the collection may be that these operations are being performed upon. If its 10,000+ elements, then this is a meaningful expense. Not trying to bash on your response just calling it like I see it :)

Comment: @boylec1986 if you're worried about efficiency do that degree, you'd be much better off with a for loop instead of a map. And that criticism is valid for basically all answers here, or anywhere a map or reduce function is used. Copying data is horrible for performance.. But it's fine for small data sets. And ease of use, clean and easy to read code is also a trade-off you can do most of the time. If you know you're regularly parsing big data sets, obviously you wouldn't use the map function, and probably not even save it to an array in memory, or maybe not even use javascript

Comment: So then you agree, using a map and/or flatMap is not a great solution to the OP's goal which is to get the typescript compiler to understand that the filter operation is forcing results to be returned of a specific type. Doing so with map/flatMap is quite inefficient as you stated no?

Comment: You're missing the point. If performance is a primary issue as you assume, no answer here is valid. I.e performance isn't a factor here. I think my answer is very relevant and correct from a type safety and DX point of view. 

If OP would've mentioned performance as a primary factor I don't think anyone would suggest to use a map or filter function. 
The question isn't about performance. You're making it about performance when it's not.

Comment: The question is about a way to tell the typescript compiler what type is returned from a filter statement.

Your solution does not answer that question.

Instead your solution recommends completely abandoning the filter statement and using a far less performant one (flatMap) in order to coerce the Typescript compiler to deduce the type of the resulting collection, when there is actually a very simple way to accomplish the OP's goal without doing that.

Please see the accepted solution and have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to define your own, completely type safe filter function that accepts an array and a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), and returns an array of different type.

Not sure how useful, but here it is:

```
function typeFilter<T, R extends T>(a: T[], f: (e: T) => e is R): R[] {
    const r: R[] = [];
    a.forEach(e => { if (f(e)) r.push(e) });
    return r;
}
```

it can be used like this:

```
const arry = [1, 2, 3, 4, "5", 6];

function isNumber(e): e is number {
    return typeof e === 'number';
}

const numArry: number[] = typeFilter(arry, isNumber);
```

Unfortunately, `isNumber()` has to be defined as separate, explicitly typed function because the compiler is not smart enough to recognize that inline function  `e => typeof e === 'number'` is a type guard too.

Comment: Since you've written out `isNumber` anyway, you can just do `const numArry = arry.filter(isNumber)`. You don't need `typeFilter`.

Answer (score 9):

The `map(...)` function signature is:

```
map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
```

On your case, the generic type `U` will be: `number | undefined`

The `filter(...)` signature is:

```
filter(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => any, thisArg?: any): T[];
```

Since the `T` is coming from the array interface signature (`Array<T>`), the return type will be an array of the same type of the `value` argument (generic type `T`). In your case `number | undefined`.

That is why your return type is `number | undefined`.

Based on this, you will need to use the cast expression. If you don't want this behaviour you can remove the `--strictNullChecks` flag.

Comment: Thanks @Diullei, it is quite informative and really great suggestion to check original type definition of built-in functions.

Comment: I'm glad to help you!

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

```
const arry = [1, 2, 3, 4, "5", 6];
const numArry = arry.reduce((acc, x) => typeof x === 'number' ? [...acc, x] : acc, [] as number[]);
```

I'm against the use of type guards because you could actually write whatever logic  and it would still work.

```
function isNumber(e: any): e is number {
    return e === undefined;
}

const numArry = arry.filter(isNumber);
```

Comment: Your objection to type guards applies to your proposed solution too; the logic could be nonsense. It's better to use a type guard so that you can make sure the logic is right in one place rather than many.

Answer (score 2):

These days you can use `Array<T>`, which provides a filter operation that supports a proper type guard:

```
const arry: Array<number|string> = [1, 2, 3, 4, "5", 6];
const numArry: number[] =
    arry.filter((e): e is number => typeof e === 'number');
```

Note that you don't get the type guard support automatically, you have to explicitly use the generic array type that comes with TypeScript.  So just declare your array object as type `Array<number|string>` and you'll be fine.

The `Array<T>` interface also has a find operation that supports a type guard for its predicate function.

This [blog](https://www.skovy.dev/blog/typescript-filter-array-with-type-guard) a nice summary of `Array<T>`.