# Typescript filtering a mixed array to one type

Tags: typescript

I have an array of two possible types and I'm trying to filter one type out but in the `forEach` below it still says that `obj` can be either type.

The only thing I have to filter on here is a constant string (it's an external API).

```
type t1 = { key: 'a' }
type t2 = { key: 'b' }

const types: (t1 | t2)[] = [];

types.filter(t => t.key === 'a').forEach(obj => { })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to tell TypeScript compiler Array.prototype.filter removes certain types from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010737/way-to-tell-typescript-compiler-array-prototype-filter-removes-certain-types-fro)

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question.  Make the filter function return type = `t is t1`:

```
types.filter((t): t is t1 => t.key === 'a').forEach(obj => { })
```