# How to I specify a method filtering an array for a certain type of element?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to implement a function which splits an array consisting of different elements into an array of elements of a certain type (specified in the function call). This is the simplified code:

```
export enum GenericElementType {
  ONE = 'type one',
  TWO = 'type two'
}

export interface TypeA {
  id: string;
  type: GenericElementType.ONE;
}

export interface TypeB {
  id: string;
  type: GenericElementType.TWO;
}

export type ElementType = TypeA | TypeB;
const arrayOfElements: (DFDElementType)[] = [];

function filterElementsOfCertainType<T extends ElementType>
  (elements: (ElementType)[], type: GenericElementType): T[] {
  return elements.filter((element: ElementType) => element.genericType === type);
}
```

This results in an error, because not every element in `ElementType` matches the return type `T`. How would I go about implementing this function correctly typed?

Here is a [Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwOJOFAlgYwFEAbYVJGAFQE8xg4BvAKDjgHkA5QuAXjgHIYtehETB+AGhZxKAdTa8BQunBgB3CJOmUAEgCVC3PoOGqAFlGDimAXyZNQkWHFyIYOAGYBDfPRp0AQUZpXAATAC44AGcYPEQAcwBuaWVgSKwxPCJScjd-YAA6TkJkuwdwaHhXdyhvXxlhACFg1jDImLiklOF07CySMgp8grk2UvtHSpc3Tx8-YQBhFpcI6NjXLtZU3syCAdyqYRH9Q3Hyp3hUuH2h0z58oIAfBrpm5-yF5PxRGLgvKCgXmobA8NzcUUiAAowYc6ABKADaAF1FMjkkwPMhEPgYLhRHAPLhiDUYVEQQscDAvK58gAeSgIEDuRChKLXHK3OgAPmkkOAHPBUJh+URSIkqh6mD6ewFsOAcMilGRy0sMGQUEQCFlUQKhOJOEhfNlkWFwjhvC5WsGbgK8Wl+HyvB4fFScNKQA) link.

Another [Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/AQUwdgrgtsDi4gE4EsDGBRANiK4AuAKgJ4AOIwA3gFDDADyAcusALzADkep5A9mCOwA0NYAQDqdVhy5lgeAO48hIggAkASumZtO3OQAtEIAVQC+VGsjB4kAMwCGqcsTIBBSiOQATAFzAAzngoYADmANwiMiB+8PwoGNi41i4gAHSM6BHmltZ2js7cAEIetN5+gcHhkdwxCPFYOPgpqeJ0WRbAVjaIDk6i3ADCJZ2+AUFWVbRRtXFoDUmE3C0aWu00UcDzTXpsKe4APv1kxYcpAxFUthBgqHjIfMC2yJjdW9b+dLYDSHj2VikAHgIoAAHjYwF5-JtEtsyAA+EQAChAMPefgIAG0ALqCOQ1OB1OaoxZkACU6OxwyMeAgiDAoGJ-lSTxeSERyOJ6NJrDhDMa1lSGxYwrxZLW2DwwHs6O47jYFDKHAAjEJRdECbMEvySWkMqYIhLgAAjGXHKQK0bsABMqumGqQRO1zVa+qohtQppAQ3livYAGZbfjYg6tQtnSt0K7UHxAnyFp89p7XJS2CzXozPt9EL9-txERj7LijbjUDj7fVic6JKSIkA) using generic typing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to tell TypeScript compiler Array.prototype.filter removes certain types from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010737/way-to-tell-typescript-compiler-array-prototype-filter-removes-certain-types-fro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "specific types" are the ones you gave, returning ElementType[], and compare the element.type with type. Think that should work. Cheers

Edit:

I think you should think of the pattern. From your last playground. elementOfTypeA: TypeA[] should be elementOfTypeA: ElementType[], you already give the required type as parameter. To put it in simpler logic, this will never work:

```
interface  person{
  id: string;
}
type teacher = person | number;

const randomVariable: person = 3;
```

although, this will:

```
interface  person{
  id: string;
}
type teacher = person | number;

const randomVariable: teacher = 3;
```

last resort:

```
function filterElementsOfCertainType<T extends ElementType>
  (elements: any[], type: GenericElementType): T[] {
  return elements.filter((element: T) => element.type !== undefined && element.type === type);
}
```

then const elementOfTypeA: TypeA[] = filterElementsOfCertainType([a, b, c], GenericElementType.TWO); will work.

it also seems to be the way the typescript documentation wants you to do it. 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

check "User-Defined Type Guards". Cheers mate.

[playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/AQUwdgrgtsDi4gE4EsDGBRANiK4AuAKgJ4AOIwA3gFDDADyAcusALzADkep5A9mCOwA0NYAQDqdVhy5lgeAO48hIggAkASumZtO3OQAtEIAVQC+VGsjB4kAMwCGqcsTIBBSiOQATAFzAAzngoYADmANwiMiB+8PwoGNi41i4gAHSM6BHmltZ2js7cAEIetN5+gcHhkdwxCPFYOPgpqeJ0WRbAVjaIDk6i3ADCJZ2+AUFWVbRRtXFoDUmE3C0aWu00UcDzTXpsKe4APv1kxYcpAxFUthBgqHjIfMC2yJjdW9b+dLYDSHj2VikAHgIoAAHjYwF5-JtEtsyAA+EQAChAMPefnsYCIAG0ALqCOQ1OB1OaoxZkACUfgIuOGRjwEEQYFApP8qSeLyQiORpKp5NYcOZjWsqQ2AEIWGxrl4QE9+F5gAAyBWChYinYSgkUtbYPDAexU7juNgUMocACMQk10SJswSQrJaQypgiOuAACMDccpCbRuwAEyW6Y2pAk+3NVrOqiu1CekBDY2m9gAZkDhNiIbtC3DK3QkdQfECKvwnz2sdcNLY7NeLM+30Qv3+3ERWPs+Ld+NQeOD9VJ4Yk5IuQA)

Comment: If I do that I get the desired element type back, however then I have the issue of assigning correctly typed variables. E.g.: const elementsOfTypeA: TypeA[] = this.filterElementsofCertainType(elements, GenericElementType.ONE) will result in an error.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you are trying to say, but this does not seem to be similar to my problem. I have an array containing two different types of elements. Now I want to filter that array, to return only one kind of elements. Then I want to be able to assign a variable to the return value, which is typed to one of the two possible elements.

Comment: Added a playground, think this should solve your issue. also wont give you an error.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot for your help! Not 100% sold on that `any[]` type of the elements array, but I guess the type safety issue here is mitigated by doing `element.type === type` check.

Answer (score 0):

This [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/AQUwdgrgtsDi4gE4EsDGBRANiK4AuAKgJ4AOIwA3gFDDADyAcusALzADkep5A9mCOwA0NYAQDqdVhy5lgeAO48hIggAkASumZtO3OQAtEIAVQC+VGsjB4kAMwCGqcsTIBBSiOQATAFzAAzngoYADmANwiMiB+8PwoGNi41i4gAHSM6BHmltZ2js7cAEIetN5+gcHhkdwxCPFYOPgpqeJ0WRbAVjaIDk6i3ADCJZ2+AUFWVbRRtXFoDUmE3C0aWu00UcDzTXpsKe4APv1kxYcpAxGofIHA9oiI9kR0tlvW-n4AFC+LZACUANoAXSkgIiVFsEDAqDwyD4wFsyEw3S+-ieAyQeHsVhSAB4CKAAB42MBefybRLbMgAPhE7xA5NefgIgMEchqcDqc3p3xAP0ZgOGRjwEEQYFAXP8qXhiKQ71pXMZP1YlLFjWsqQ2LE1rN+a2weBujO47jYFDKHAAjEJtdF2bMEqruekmKYInrgAAjQ3HKSm0bsABMVumtqQnIdzVaLqobtQXpAQxNZvYAGYg2zYqH7QsIyt0FGqJcwP4eNhUpgeCF3lKkeLUejMWAUu8-vZBO7BKgASyM-UuRGJD8fmEgA) should work. However, this is the correct typing:

```js
function filterElementsOfCertainType<T extends ElementType>
  (elements: T[], type: GenericElementType): T[] {
  return elements.filter((element: T) => element.type === type);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the code works. The issue still persists though - if the passed array is typed to be one of the three available element types, it is not assignable. I attached another playground link to my question to better show what I mean.

Comment: `const elementOfTypeA: TypeA[] = filterElementsOfCertainType([a, b, c], GenericElementType.TWO) as TypeA[];`

Comment: That works, but that removes the type safety all together - e.g. passing `GenericElementType.ONE` would not result in an error.