# Narrow return type of find from discriminated union array

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, discriminated-union

I often use code like in example below and was wondering if there is some smart way to type the `find` results without having to do explicit type assertion.

```
type Foo = { type: "Foo" };
type Goo = { type: "Goo" };
type Union = Foo | Goo;

const arr: Union[] = [];
const foo = arr.find(a => a.type === "Foo") as Foo;
```

If the `as Foo` type assertion is left out, the result is of type `Union` even though it can only return type `Foo`.

What's the cleanest way of fixing the type of `find` to return the narrowed type in examples like these?

Edit: This problem could be also applicable to `filter` and other similar methods.

Edit2: Suggested similar question's accepted answer ([Way to tell TypeScript compiler Array.prototype.filter removes certain types from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010737/way-to-tell-typescript-compiler-array-prototype-filter-removes-certain-types-fro)) shows that by using type guard in the predicate for `find/filter` the return value can be narrowed down.

How should this type guard function look to narrow down any discriminated union if e.g. the distinguishing string literal is always under `type` key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Way to tell TypeScript compiler Array.prototype.filter removes certain types from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010737/way-to-tell-typescript-compiler-array-prototype-filter-removes-certain-types-fro)

Comment: Not completely but it helps. Now just to figure out how to write some generic type guard function that can narrow down discriminated unions like this so I would be able to write `arr.find(isTypeFromUnion("Foo"))`.

Comment: You could define the callback function of `find` as type guard like this: `const maybeFoo = arr.find((a): a is Foo => a.type === "Foo"); // Foo | undefined` . [TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=81&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKpIC4oCJ5y5QC+A3AFCbQDiCyaG4EOuthJFVUAqgHYCWcXvQJQAPlDYVyAYyEBnYFACGAJ1U4+g3gG0AuvX3S5vRVAC2ykACMIolGtUA6AGb9eAEwAUX5QEocZSh+eVg6JAA+FScuJDi8Alw-UigAelSwxAkAV08IN14ID3ISoA)

Comment: That just moves the `as Foo` to `a is Foo` which means I would still need to explicitly write the type

Comment: Afaik there is currently no way for the compiler to automatically infer the type guard and narrow the union, see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7657) and [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20812).

Comment: What I'm asking now is how to write a type guard that narrows discriminated unions just like it is narrowed in e.g. switch over it's type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By now we can have it as a reasonably generic util:

```
export function isOfType<
  GenericType extends string,
  Union extends { type: GenericType },
  SpecificType extends GenericType,
>(val: SpecificType) {
  return (obj: Union): obj is Extract<Union, { type: SpecificType }> =>
    obj.type === val;
}

const found = arr.find(isOfType('Foo'));
```

Inspired by Trevor Dixon via https://stackoverflow.com/a/61102770

Comment: I didn't know you can use `Extract` that way. I would expect you only get `{ type: SpecificType } | undefined` as a return type of the `.find` but you actually get the whole thing. That's absolutely amazing, thanks!

Comment: This is awesome! How would something similar look like for an array of types, e.g. `arr.find(isOfTypes(['Foo', 'Bar']))`?

Answer (score 14):

If you want a generator for user-defined type guard functions returning a type predicate that discriminates discriminated unions, it might look something like this:

```
function discriminate<K extends PropertyKey, V extends string | number | boolean>(
    discriminantKey: K, discriminantValue: V
) {
    return <T extends Record<K, any>>(
        obj: T & Record<K, V extends T[K] ? T[K] : V>
    ): obj is Extract<T, Record<K, V>> =>
        obj[discriminantKey] === discriminantValue;
}
```

If I call `discriminate("type", "Foo")`, the result is a function with a signature similar to `<T>(obj: T)=>obj is Extract<T, {type: "Foo"}>`.  (I say it's *similar* because the actual return value restricts `T` to just types with `"type"` as a key and a value you can assign `"Foo"` to.)  Let's see how it works:

```
const foo = arr.find(discriminate("type", "Foo")); // Foo | undefined 
const goos = arr.filter(discriminate("type", "Goo"));  // Goo[]
```

Looks good.  And here's what happens if you pass inapplicable field/values:

```
const mistake1 = arr.find(discriminate("hype", "Foo")); // error!
// ------------------->   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Union is not assignable to Record<"hype", any>.
const mistake2 = arr.find(discriminate("type", "Hoo")); // error!
// ------------------->   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Union is not assignable to ((Foo | Goo) & Record<"type", "Hoo">)
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKpIC4oCJ5y5QC+A3ALABQm0A4gsmhuBDrvYSRdS1AKoA7AJZwBjAlAA+UDtyhUAxqIDOwKAEMATppyCRAgNoBdRse5UqAMwCuAhcH1QAJkOULNQgLZCB64BAAeAGkoCAAPfwEnZSgABU04SE1QIIgQABooADVQiIgomNUPAQBzKSgBa08AIwhNcuqEABsIdQEAPgAKKihe51d3Lx824FSQHCDMlzcPb18BYCz1JutWbKoASjQevs0IYGtNMQCAFVzI6KgAJQglTSdgzLaQdq6dvr64aoArHDOAMmutzg90e2XO+UuJwMQRMAH4oNDYVAcFl2u8oBscF9vlBXFAAKIRTTqeynTI3O4PSbZV7IdGUD4fHEGaaDOYjMYmJA8-ozIbzRbLVbcYgWShKASqKCWBgoLSaAB0lh8Tk6bNmw38nVwNFwmXwCFwGw2pCgAHpzbAGNJbE4ICqBBAnPIJSo1CUEDF5dplUImv5NOqBprfNrdSx9XgOMbTb1LTIEMZxZLpd5VOoANYQACMjAVfqiwf5HPDAAtIwaCLGzQm6glNABCKgJgC07Y7na7nfafQAfgPB0PhyORy2rXpRHiYgI4Gp1MplEISr5qi0MIhKSCHrgK5Ao892orFO6oOngFmIAAmfO+x1qjUCvwQHV6g0ACSNJtrVvrIOblBtt2wFdr2vSjhBkGDuO-DCFO+KzvOi7Lqu67AIgnSdBI0gcFsgJbqCEb7h+RrtBs4pAA)

Comment: Yes this works like charm. Exactly what I expected. Could you also expand this to negation and union? `a.type !== "Foo"` and `a.type === "Foo" || a.type === "Goo"`

Comment: Yes, most likely.   Negation would use `Exclude` instead of `Extract`, and for union you'll need to accept an array/rest parameter of type `V[]` and check each element in the array.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the jcalz's code from answer above extended with the negation and union.

```
export function isDiscriminate<K extends PropertyKey, V extends string | number | boolean>(
    discriminantKey: K, discriminantValue: V | V[]
) {
    return <T extends Record<K, any>>(
        obj: T & Record<K, V extends T[K] ? T[K] : V>
    ): obj is Extract<T, Record<K, V>> =>
        Array.isArray(discriminantValue) 
            ? discriminantValue.some(v => obj[discriminantKey] === v)
            : obj[discriminantKey] === discriminantValue;
}

export function isNotDiscriminate<K extends PropertyKey, V extends string | number | boolean>(
    discriminantKey: K, discriminantValue: V | V[]
) {
    return <T extends Record<K, any>>(
        obj: T & Record<K, V extends T[K] ? T[K] : V>
    ): obj is Exclude<T, Record<K, V>> =>
        Array.isArray(discriminantValue)
            ? discriminantValue.some(v => obj[discriminantKey] === v)
            : obj[discriminantKey] === discriminantValue;
}
```

And usage:

```
type A = { type: "A" };
type B = { type: "B" };
type C = { type: "C" };
type Union = A | B | C;

const arr: Union[] = [];
arr.find(isDiscriminate("type", "A")); // A
arr.find(isDiscriminate("type", ["A", "B"])); // A | B
arr.find(isNotDiscriminate("type", "A")); // B | C
arr.find(isNotDiscriminate("type", ["A", "B"])) // C
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is excellent, but it's hard to understand. I went with something like this. It's less reusable, only working on one type, but it's much easier to read.

```
function isType<V extends Union['type']>(val: V) {
  return (obj: Union):
      obj is Extract<Union, {type: V}> => obj.type === val;
}

const found = arr.find(isType('Foo'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Thank you to jcalz for [the excellent accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59054248/2097348).

I have annotated a slightly different flavor of a factory for predicate guards:

```
function hasProp<K extends PropertyKey, V extends string | number | boolean>(k: K, v: V) {
  
  // All candidate types might have key `K` of any type
  type Candidate = Partial<Record<K, any>> | null | undefined

  // All matching subtypes of T must have key `K` equal value `V`
  type Match<T extends Candidate> = Extract<T, Record<K, V>>

  return <T extends Candidate>(obj: T): obj is Match<T> => (
    obj?.[k] === v
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add autocomplete for the "types" (extension of @edzis answer)

```
export function isOfType<
  Union extends { type: string },
  SpecificType extends Union['type'],
>(val: SpecificType) {
  return (obj: Union): obj is Extract<Union, { type: SpecificType }> =>
    obj.type === val;
}


const found = arr.find(isOfType('Foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension of @edzis and @SEG answers:

To narrow to a subset of types:

```
export function isOfType<
  Union extends { type: string },
  SpecificType extends Union['type'],
>(val: SpecificType[] | SpecificType) {
  return (obj: Union): obj is Extract<Union, { type: SpecificType }> =>
    Array.isArray(val) ? val.some((a) => a === obj.type) : obj.type === val;
}
```