# Filtering a discriminated union with OR operator

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Consider the following type definitions:

```
type ClipBase = { duration: number; }

type AudioClip = ClipBase & {
    type: "audio"; 
    volume: number;
}

type VideoClip = ClipBase & {
    type: "video"; 
    height: number;
    width: number;
}

type MediaClip = ClipBase & {
    type: "media"; 
    url: string;
}

type Clip =  VideoClip | AudioClip | MediaClip;
```

I would like to use `.filter` on an array of Clips and narrow down the type. I use the following helper function, borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760898/9627628):

```
export function isType<
  GenericType extends string,
  Union extends { type: GenericType },
  SpecificType extends GenericType,
>(val: SpecificType) {
  return (obj: Union): obj is Extract<Union, { type: SpecificType }> =>
    obj.type === val;
}
```

This works fine if I filter for only one kind of clip:

```
function getVideoClips(clips: Clip[]) {
  return clips.filter(isType("video")); // VideoClip[]
}
```

However, if I want to get a subset of the discriminated union, TypeScript gives the original type `Clip[]` back, even though it should be simple to infer what types the filter should output.

```
function getAudioAndMediaClips(clips: Clip[]) {
  return clips.filter(clip => isType("audio")(clip) || isType("media")(clip)); // Clip[]
}
```

[Full example on the Typescript Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgSzAIQIYGdoF4oG8oAmArgE6rAID2AdgFxTVEC2ARhCQNxQC+AUL6EhQAgkQJV4SKDkkoM0AGR5eUVVEER6AIlRiqWrirUA3SnGaaGzNp158B4aADUEBCJVnTYiOZihLcI1UNbWNXdwMoIKgACwgEAHMY4HpGVnYOaIB3V2AY1OsMu34NKABZCHFUTxkfND8A6JCoLSZKhFRI6NI4enRgEgRqBMz7UprVFzcPHygAHxE9GakFiqrZTN4IAA8wShJgKAAzImoAYwoaKAR0ABVHAB4jAHEIanYEM-uhHeA3gnQUH6g2GABojABVahUahQX7-QH4Zqvd6DL6OHjg1QAZUgZwQR0+32g8OoAKgKI+6Mg4IAfAAKYyoXpQXEQfGE6kQACUylUJAgwFIsPplBYACt6FCYdz6GLxddAQBRbYDVAXB7SmigvDqRz0NkcokY7i06S06LygB0pSwdqgTLgo34J3Ol1hCUFU3csnQ9LOPnQ9FkAG0ALq8wL8wXCqABpDoK2EuB-Ej0m7E+laMLTLTc7lcAD0hag3uWYHDxV4rouMKgnuAonElGEZLWHV9-sDwZ84cjRgFQpIsPjYETydTXakWDNGccWd0zbzU7AvLmCznkCzbSqy9H+aLJdDYbsQA)

What can I do to help TypeScript to successfully infer multiple types from a discriminated union, without having to write specific helper functions for each pair of types?

Comment:  This isn't a [mre].  Your `isType()` function will return `obj is never` the way you've been calling it, and your second `renderMany` doesn't even do anything with `clip`, so I don't know what you're doing.  Could you please try your code out in an IDE, fix anything wrong that isn't related to your question, and then [edit] the code here?

Comment: ... once you fix that, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVY3Zw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes I made a mistake in the example in the second renderMany. I fixed the example and added a playground link to it.

Comment: @jcalz yes your solution is good, please write up an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) are not inferred from function implementations, so `clip => isType("audio")(clip) || isType("media")(clip)` isn't a type guard function.   There is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#38390](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38390) to allow the compiler to automatically see certain simple function implementations as being type guard functions, but for now it's not part of the language. Until and unless such a feature is implemented, if you want a function to be a type guard function you'll need to [annotate its return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) with a type predicate.

For example:

```
function getAudioAndMediaClips(clips: Clip[]) {
  return clips.filter((clip): clip is AudioClip | MediaClip =>
    isType("audio")(clip) || isType("media")(clip)); // (AudioClip | MediaClip)[]
}
```

Here you are explicitly telling the compiler that the callback returns `clip is AudioClip | MediaClip`, and so the return type of the whole function is `(AudioClip | MediaClip)[]`.

---

If you don't want to do that manually, you'll need to write a more general type guard function which can act on both single `type` as well as multiple `type`s.  For example, you can rewrite `isType` to be [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) and take multiple discriminant values instead of just one:

```
function isType<T extends string | number | boolean | null | undefined>(
  ...types: T[]
) {
  return <U extends { type: any }>(
    obj: U
  ): obj is Extract<U, { type: T }> => 
    types.includes(obj[key]);
}
```

You could use this like before:

```
function getVideoClips(clips: Clip[]) {
  return clips.filter(isType("video")); // VideoClip[]
}
```

But you could also pass an additional argument:

```
function getAudioAndMediaClips(clips: Clip[]) {
  return clips.filter(isType("audio", "media")); //  (AudioClip | MediaClip)[]
}
```

Looks good!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgSzAIQIYGdoF4oG8oAmArgE6rAID2AdgFxTVEC2ARhCQNxQC+AUL6EhQAgkQJV4SKDkkoM0AGR5eUVVEER6AIlRiqWrirUA3SnGaaGzNp158B4aADUEBCJVnTYiOZihLcI1UNbWNXdwMoIKgACwgEAHMY4HpGVnYOaIB3V2AY1OsMu34NKABZCHFUTxkfND8A6JCoLSZKhFRI6NI4enRgEgRqBMz7UprVFzcPHygAHxE9GakFiqrZTN4IAA8wShJgKAAzImoAYwoaKAR0ABVHAB4jAHEIanYEM-uhHeA3gnQUH6g2GABojABVahUahQX7-QH4Zqvd6DL6OHjg1QAZUgZwQR0+32g8OoAKgKI+6Mg4IAfAAKYyoXpQXEQfGE6kQACUylUJAgwFIsPplBYACt6FCYdz6GLxddAQBRbYDVAXB7SmigvDqRz0NkcokY7i06S06LygB0pSwdqgTLgo34J3Ol1hCUFU3csnQ9LOPnQ9FkAG0ALq8wL8wXCqABpDoK2EuB-Ej0m7E+laMLTLTc7lcAD0hag3uWYHDxV4rouMKgnuAonElGEZLWHV9-sDwZ84cjRgFQpIsPjYETydTXakWDNGccWd0zbzU7AvLmCznkCzbSqy9H+aLJdDYbsQA)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function to merge `is` functions

```
function OR<T, A extends T, B extends T>(
  check1: (v: T) => v is A,
  check2: (v: T) => v is B
): (val: T) => val is (A | B) {
  return ((val: T) => check1(val) || check2(val)) as any
}

function getAudioAndMediaClips2(clips: Clip[]) {
  let result = clips.filter(
    // ^?
    // let result: (AudioClip | MediaClip)[]
    OR(
      isType("audio"),
      isType("media")
    )
  );
  return result;
}
```