# Narrow discriminated union using nested key

Tags: typescript, filter, type-conversion, discriminated-union

I am trying to filter a discriminated union array into separate arrays of its union types. I stumbled into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050071/narrow-return-type-of-find-from-discriminated-union-array) which gives generic discriminators.

Unfortunately the data I'm using does not have the discriminating key at the highest level.

```
type Foo = { meta: {type: "Foo"} };
type Goo = { meta: {type: "Goo"} };
type Union = Foo | Goo;
```

I fixed this by changing the discriminator function in the other post to expect the "meta" object one level down.

```
function discriminateNested<K extends PropertyKey, V extends string | number | boolean>(
    discriminantKey: K, discriminantValue: V
) {
    return <T extends Record<PropertyKey, any>>(
        obj: T & Record<"meta", Record<K, V extends T["meta"][K] ? T["meta"][K] : V>>
    ): obj is Extract<T, Record<"meta", Record<K, V>>> =>
        obj["meta"][discriminantKey] === discriminantValue;
}
```

Is there a more generic way to do this? Perhaps by specifying a nested key with a string like `discriminateNested("meta.type", "Foo")`?

Comment: Actually you just have a `discriminate<'meta', {type: 'Foo'}>` here

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXrkJm) what you're looking for?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is for `discriminateNested()` to take a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of keys and discriminate based on the value at the corresponding nested property.  You could do this with dot-separated strings instead, but this way is a little more straightforward in terms of typings.

First we should define `NestedRecord<K, V>` where `K` is a tuple of keys.  We want `NestedRecord<["a", "b", "c"], string>` to be equivalent to `{a: {b: {c: string}}}`.  It could look like this:

```
type NestedRecord<K extends PropertyKey[], V> =
  K extends [infer K0 extends PropertyKey, ...infer KR extends PropertyKey[]] ?
  { [P in K0]: NestedRecord<KR, V> } : V;
```

That's a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) that uses [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to parse `K` and build the nested type.

And now `discriminatedNested()` could be implemented like this:

```
function discriminateNested<K extends PropertyKey[], V extends string | number | boolean>(
  discriminantKeys: [...K], discriminantValue: V
) {
  return <T extends NestedRecord<K, string | number | boolean>>(
    obj: T
  ): obj is Extract<T, NestedRecord<K, V>> =>
    discriminantKeys.reduce<any>((acc, k) => acc[k], obj) === discriminantValue;
}
```

This takes `discriminantKeys` of tuple type `K` (well, `[...K]`, which just hints that you want it to be a tuple and not an unordered array; see the description of [microsoft/TypeScript#39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) that implemented variadic tuple types) and a `discriminant value` of type `V`, and returns a custom type guard function which [`Extracts`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) the union member(s) of the input type `T` to just those assignable to `Nestedrecord<K, V>>`  The implementation uses [the `reduce()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on `discriminantKeys` to perform the nested indexing.

---

Let's test it out:

```
type Foo = { meta: { type: "Foo" }, a: string };
type Goo = { meta: { type: "Goo" }, b: number };
type Union = Foo | Goo;

const discFoo = discriminateNested(["meta", "type"], "Foo");
/* const discFoo: <T extends {
    meta: {
        type: string | number | boolean;
    };
}>(obj: T) => obj is Extract<T, {
    meta: {
        type: "Foo";
    };
}> */

const u: Union = Math.random() < 0.5 ?
  { meta: { type: "Foo" }, a: "abc" } : { meta: { type: "Goo" }, b: 123 };

if (discFoo(u)) {
  u // Foo
  console.log(u.a.toUpperCase());
} else {
  u // Goo
  console.log(u.b.toFixed(2));
}
```

Looks good.  The `discFoo` type guard function accepts any input with a `{meta:{type: string | number | boolean}}` type and filters in or out those union members assignable to `{meta:{type:"Foo"}}`.  When you pass it a value of type `Union`, the true branch narrows to `Foo` and the false branch narrows to `Goo`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/FAFwngDgpgBAclAziKATASlAxgewE6oA8A0jFAB4oB2qiMACnjtHuMVGANoC6ANDADUAfDAC8wGDFIVqtGJwCWVAGZQ8UgAxlKUGnUbM1bDvwB05pavXF022fqYtjXbtxgB+CTADe8+jCVNbgAueCQUDGx8Iht+YRgAXxhQgQBuYGBlAFcqLBAFHCoYVAVELDwFAFslAEMUBGQ0EjtdOQMnMHYXOJa9GGQKqgBzGAAfGCosyoAjNTGYaZwcABsoGqohAAovErKK6qp1kC7EUM5zU2I+YtLyqtqqEAEa5ayoFOAASh8vPCgQLJ4IqEAAqvTkDQimFwBBI-AGShG40mMzm40WKzWGy2XkkOGmACtQiCvJ9QviCQE6ABRSh4Gp5UH8SFoaHROGCIQiURCXE3Pb3Q6PE6mP6oLJYKCEdZgLabBlYfgAa2+PJgCs4SuuFNVolE-LuByOz1eUHSCQyuCoyANADElmIDftavVwmhNpwAESVf41T38T3gaCe66e+04T2fdIAegAVDArTbdlhw6FQeC6N4+T6QDVQlnJIXC0H3v0QIMkRMprN1Oilqt1ukiwlzVsKcTVSIKVSYLTywyQEyfkWc3nh0Xi5BS2Glp6m4WW8AEiJY9GMiWYOHHb5R-mYCXQjOI4l+GOEcNEukNwBxB36ne+vcHmCe2-HhL8aahFE1y+gKcwAAqlQBRFPqW7jG+6SJiAMBZKEwGgY6ACydQABaiusqA4JUmzfIQMAaKYACsHheA+uZPlOh7hp6J7qoeNTTFgdFJHuu4+Pu1Evm+rGfqEACMABMADMf7AAoygwJsybhpsWSfN8BZwTA0bRpuSxeImmKmMsOBDPJpg1KYIA4IBEAsAAwjUiBQHhUZLmQyy2eOWSqepb5aYUiA6XpBlZKY0wmTgtoKOQ7pCYp5oZEAA)