# Typescript and Array.filter() working together

Tags: typescript

When using `Array.filter()` I'm not sure how to achieve what I'm describing below.

I don't want to create a new type just for this (but if there's no other way around, that's okay):

```js
interface GPSLocation {
  lat: number
  lng: number
}

interface House {
  address: string
  location?: GPSLocation
}

const house01: House = {
  address: '123 street'
}

const house02: House = {
  address: '123 street',
  location: {
    lat: 111.111,
    lng: 222.222
  }
}

const allHouses = [house01, house02]

// Infered by Typescript: const gpsLocationList: (GPSLocation | undefined)[]
// Expected: const gpsLocationList: (GPSLocation)[]
const gpsLocationList = allHouses.filter((house) => house.location !== undefined).map(house => house.location)
```

Comment: You have to create a custom guard to tell TypeScript the returned is guaranteed not to contain undefined. It is not able [to infer it without a guard](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033938/227299 and its playground link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't TypeScript infer type from filtered arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032214/why-cant-typescript-infer-type-from-filtered-arrays)

Comment: Please don't close this a duplicate of [Why can't TypeScript infer type from filtered arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032214/why-cant-typescript-infer-type-from-filtered-arrays). It is not simple to infer the solution to this from the given link even if it is how I got to my final solution for this exact problem.

Comment: Added a third option which utilizes .flatMap(). FYI  @JuanMendes

Comment: @ItayMaman That's awesome!

Answer (score 8):

### Make your filter callback be a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) that forces location not to be optional.

I know there's an existing post [with a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033938/227299), but since it's not that easy to infer the solution for this case (mapping to an optional subproperty), and I had to do the same thing in the past few days, I will share this here.

```
const gpsLocationList = allHouses
    .filter((house): house is House & {location: GPSLocation} => {
         return house.location !== undefined;
    })
    .map(house => house.location);
```

I would prefer to split this into a separate declaration for clarity.

```
type HouseLocationRequired = House & {location: GPSLocation};

const gpsLocationList = allHouses
    .filter((house): house is HouseLocationRequired => {
         return house.location !== undefined;
    })
    .map(house => house.location);
```

If you want to really minimize duplication of types, you can use `Required<T>` and `Pick<>`

```
type HouseLocationRequired = House & Required<Pick<House, "location">>;
```

And abstract it one level further:

```
type RequiredSubProperty<Class, Prop extends keyof Class> = Class & Required<Pick<Class, Prop>>;

const gpsLocationList = allHouses
    .filter((house): house is RequiredSubProperty<House, "location">  => {
         return house.location !== undefined;
    })
    .map(house => house.location);
```

At that point, you may as well abstract checking the sub-property with type safety.

```
function subPropFilter<T>(prop: keyof T) {
    return (obj: T): obj is RequiredSubProperty<T, typeof prop> => {
        return obj[prop] !== undefined;
    }
}

const gpsLocationList = allHouses.
    .filter(subPropFilter("location"))
    .map(house => house.location)
```

Then why not abstract the entire process adding mapping to that sub-property?

```
function getNonNullSubProps<T, Prop extends keyof T>(arr: T[], prop: Prop) {
    return arr.filter(subPropFilter(prop)).map(obj => obj[prop] as typeof obj[Prop]) 
}

const gpsLocationList = getNonNullSubProps(allHouses, "location");
```

See [live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOIAUDKAZA9guMYXEZAbwChlkAbQgLmRAFcBbAI2itpAHNGWHLgF8KFUJFiIUACVzMAzikrU4AEzVQIChYwVgooXtxr5CxEAH5GGHGaIkKoighL7kAC3lKADAEZGOUUUAF5ybnVNbV1kAHI-ACYAZmR9LQgwWKcxVxB3L2CfBMDvUPDVDS0dRnjk1IMIDNiAGhN7C0YValoGZD9+gDp+v1bunn5kBKmBqYTuUWcXNzBkOBoaIKUFZDCAbQLfEc9SooBdMQowAE8ABxQAJQgAR2ZgLTVMZnZ0KFw7qGuAB4AMJ0HTNZA-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-HybZpH6AkBIqSK6nHlpOmlPpgUoOGyAigp-LPIKCEBbpwVKiQ5aVvRHl1l5zGPs+yXBA5hUuVJYV5HJBHZVFYApMp6zxRp17abpqWGRlkZUkOsYAlcMqlPKTUkCqDWlEVlmle5NaVd5NV+aUS1OfNIChUsrUCe1kVkQALASqy9Wp-VaeeMZ-FeWkKrZcr3ttdVKHtQUHUdsmnUJxUgJ1ACsBJdmAvYgP2g4Xn8CgLrdwQKHN72hUAA) that shows how awesome the suggestions are as you're using these utilities.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed annoying.

Here are two common approaches.

(1) Use `as` to force the compiler to treat it as `GPSLocation`:

```
const gpsLocationList = allHouses.filter((house) => house.location !== undefined)
  .map(house => house.location as GPSLocation)
```

(2) Use a function that throws an error if its input is falsy:

```
function reify<T>(t: T|null|undefined): T {
  if (t === null || t === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`got a falsy value`)
  }
  return t
}

const gpsLocationList = allHouses.filter((house) => house.location !== undefined)
  .map(house => reify(house.location))
```

### Update

There is actually a third approach: use [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```
const gpsLocationList: string[] = allHouses.flatMap(
  house => house.location !== undefined ? [house.location] : [])
```

This actually works well and is 100% safe. The downsides are:

- `.flatMap()` is not available in all platform. You will need to use `target: "es2019"` in your `tsconfig.json` file.
- It's not very readable.

Comment: Interesting approaches. Just casting feels like cheapening out but I love the "function that guarantees its input is not null" guard.