# Typescript inferring defined value as undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the below array which can have either be an object or undefined. Even after filtering the results to contain all defined values, typescript still says it could be undefined

```js
interface Bob {
    name: string;
}

type BobDetails = undefined | Bob;

const myArray: BobDetails[] = [{ name:  "Bob"}, undefined];
myArray[0].name; // expected Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)

var filter = myArray.filter(arr => arr?.name);
filter[0].name; // still Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)
```

How do make Typescript know that `filter[]` will have only Bob[] and no undefined. I am aware we might be able to do with `!` but I want the normal flow to realise it.

[Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=11&pln=1&pc=14#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsBGyDeAoZQ5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG48BfPMATwAcUNMAIhDBxgAG2rIAvMgCuIACYQYoCAuQAfNFhZ4E6ELWSlOAQShQ4nKvyEjx1ANoBdackc5iZSoQBE-X1YAGjlFZVUFZxYTc0tORwAGZwA6EnImZAB6TOQAeUwAKwgEMGRgSW50ampgTDFOZAByeSUVEDVG5IAKACYAVgBmHoBKPDwANzgoZBUxSGmZGIsrZNn5rqmFgD5kTYB%20VO9hljXoRJS0iAzsmjBxMSyc-KKSsoqqmrqG5rC2ju7%20kNRkA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that, you need to have your filter function be a [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). Right now, `arr => arr?.name` is just a function that returns a `string | undefined`. You and i can figure out what implications that will have for the resulting array, but typescript needs a bit more.

If you change the function so that it returns a boolean, and you give it the special return type `arr is Bob`, then typescript knows that if `true` is returned, then it can deduce that arr is a `Bob`. And the filter method knows that this will then result in a `Bob[]`:

```
var filter = myArray.filter((arr): arr is Bob => arr?.name !== undefined);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsBGyDeAoZQ5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG48BfPMATwAcUNMAIhDBxgAG2rIAvMgCuIACYQYoCAuQAfNFhZ4E6ELWSlOAQShQ4nKvyEjx1ANoBdackc5iZSoQBE-X1YAGjlFZVUFZxYTc0tORwAGZwA6EnImZAB6TOQAeUwAKwgEMGRgSW50ampgTDFOZAByeSUVEDVG5IAKACYAVgBmHoBKPDwANzgoZBUxSGmZGIsrZNn5rq6pqGGqLbLJfmkAPmQtgH5U72QAQikZFvD2hWGWNehElLSIDOyaMHExFkcvkiiV9shKtVavUmg82h1uv0hqMgA)

Comment: `Right now, arr => arr?.name is just a function that returns a string | undefined` how can this be possible? We are filtering the results right?

Comment: This is a neat solution although I guess its the same as `var filter = myArray.filter(arr => arr?.name) as Bob[];`. You're simply moving the cast to the type guard after all.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph The answer to that is probably : Typescript cannot infer this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032214/why-cant-typescript-infer-type-from-filtered-arrays) may answer that question also.

Comment: The type on `arr => arr?.name` is the same as the type on `arr => Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'foo' : undefined`, but only the first one should result in `filter` being a `Bob[]`. Using only the implicit type information, there isn't a way for typescript to know whether the array will be narrowed or not. So you need to use a more explicit type to give typescript more information.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the array being:
BobDetails[] = [undefined, undefined];

Then filter[0].name; will also be undefined. For simplicity you can check the length of filter as:

```
if(filter.length>0){ filter[0].name; ... your code}
```

Comment: How does this resolve the error? it still shows `Object is possibly undefined`