# Why does filter not change the possible type?

Tags: typescript

In the code below, why is `result` not a type of `Date` (instead of `Date|null`)?

```
function tester(dates:Date[], x:(_:Date)=>Date|null) {
  // the type of result is still "Date|null", even after filtering out the nulls...
  let result = dates.map(d => x(d)).filter(d => d !== null); 
}
```

I put together a quick [sample playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZ1QJwBQBMCGqaAXACKEoDaAugDSIAex2ADmRQJQC8AfOagB8wIADYiOiAN4AoRIhEooiTOlFKuiAkQB0AW3ws8iXozwcO24DBFYjJ3IgCEXDcLEcA3NIC%20QA).

Comment: Because, in it's current form, TS does not know it changes anything. You can type the predicate as a type guard and it will work as expected. `<T>(d: T | null): d is T => d !== null` or `<T>(d: T): Exclude<T, null> => d !== null`

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62032214/15261914

Comment: See part of this answer to a question that mentions this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46700791/15261914

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is not inferring that your arrow function is meant to be a type guard. You need to pass an explicit type guard like:

```
function tester(dates: Date[], x: (p: Date) => Date | null) {
  return dates.map(d => x(d)).filter((d): d is Date => d !== null);
}
```

Or you can create a utility function that you can use anywhere:

```
function isDefined<T>(arg: T | null | undefined): arg is T {
  return arg !== null && arg !== undefined;
}

function tester(dates: Date[], x: (p: Date) => Date | null) {
  return dates.map(d => x(d)).filter(isDefined);
}
```