# How to use filter for type narrowing?

Tags: typescript

How can I achieve type narrowing using filter? I was surpsrised to see in the code below that `error` has type `Outcome` and not `ErrorOutcome`.

```
type Outcome = ResultOutcome | ErrorOutcome;
type ResultOutcome = {
  id: string;
  result: string;
};
type ErrorOutcome = {
  id: string;
  error: string;
};

function isErrorOutcome(val: Outcome): val is ErrorOutcome {
  return (val as ErrorOutcome).error !== undefined
}

function isResultOutcome(val: Outcome): val is ResultOutcome {
  return (val as ResultOutcome).result !== undefined
}

results.filter(result => isErrorOutcome(result)).forEach(error => ...)
```

Also, a related questions: would it be more Typescript ideomatic to define `ResultOutcome` and `ErrorOutcome` as classes and use the `instanceof` operator instead?

Comment: I think, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010737/way-to-tell-typescript-compiler-array-prototype-filter-removes-certain-types-fro) contains, what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript can see that `error` is an `ErrorOutcome` if you supply `isErrorOutcome` directly to `filter`:

```
results.filter(isErrorOutcome).forEach(error => ...)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8grsAxgewLbQLxQEoQM5wA2w8Sa0APlAKIBOtytpK6A3AFCiQ75EkItMUAN7soUAJYATAFxQ8wWhIB2Acw7javYnIVK1HAL4cu0OgyYDyULKPHTdilerFQI9Ro-0vj7dgDM4ZURgCWRlSTxzRmZyAAoANwBDQjlY9ABKOWTCSJoPSzJ0EVctYDhaCMSUqCS8fIt0iAyAOncLKABCDCwgqQh-FQgpdkM-QODQ8MjcAmIm6tTYK0zsmol62b4mks0IcsqoRdrN7X4i5patOeAunqg+gaGRsfYUZQUoa748NJWIADaAF0bFAAcIHFAAEQARihABovmc5FCklDDIiIbJoQAmBFuAoogBGhCSAAt0UCOOxvsQ8C1BsR3HENtFCoJWv5GNQkogyXF2owbAA+XbiKDvPDIQgQFqEZCqAUFDJGFVAA)

Apparently the `is ErrorOutcome` aspect doesn't survive the arrow function wrapper. You could add it back though:

```
results.filter((result): result is ErrorOutcome => isErrorOutcome(result)).forEach(error => ...);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8grsAxgewLbQLxQEoQM5wA2w8Sa0APlAKIBOtytpK6A3AFCiQ75EkItMUAN7soUAJYATAFxQ8wWhIB2Acw7javYnIVK1HAL4cu0OgyYDyULKPHTdilerFQI9Ro-0vj7dgDM4ZURgCWRlSTxzRmZyAAoANwBDQjlY9ABKOWTCSJoPSzJ0EVctYDhaCMSUqCS8fIt0iAyAOncLKABCDCwgqQh-FQgpdkM-QODQ8MjcAmIm6tTYK0zsmol62b4mks0IcsqoRdrN7X4i5patOeAunqg+gaGRsfYUZQUoa748NJWIADaAF0bFAAcIHFAAEQARihABovmc5FCklDDIiIbJoQAmBFuAoogBGhCSAAt0UCOOxvsQ8C1BsR3HE4rTgFkkTc8tFCoIbAA+SI8hZsjKtfyMahJRBkuLtRgC3biKDvPDIQgQFqEZCqOUFDJGA1AA)