# How to do a "OfType" in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I've one class named `Step`, and a subclass `StopStep` that extends it.

I'm trying to extract the list of `StopStep` inside a `Step` collection, but I'm not sure sure how to proceed. I've been looking around a bit, but I can't find a solution.

I've tried this:

```
filter(steps: Step[]):StopStep[]{
  return steps.filter(s=>s instanceof StopStep);
}
```

I guess it filters properly but still returns a collection of Step and not StopStep.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you always create the objects as the class instances? as `new StopStep()` and not `{} as StopStep`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Way to tell TypeScript compiler Array.prototype.filter removes certain types from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010737/way-to-tell-typescript-compiler-array-prototype-filter-removes-certain-types-fro)