# Stricter type assertion in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, type-assertion

So lets's say I have

```js
declare function doSomething(...args: any[]): any

interface Example {
    a: number
    b: number
}

doSomething({a: 2, b: 1, c: 10} as Example)
```

This does not report an error as that object extends `Example` and typescript is happy, so I end up using an ugly identity function:

```
function cast<T>(arg: T) {
    return arg
}

doSomething(cast<Example>({a: 2, b: 1, c: 10})) // yay, error
```

It irritates the heck out of me that I need to actually call an %^#% no-op function just to do a proper type cast. I end up declaring it in every file that needs it just to give the js compiler better chances of optimizing it out.

Is there any ts magic I don't know about that can avoid the function call?

And yes, I know I can do this:

```
const x: Example = {a: 2, b: 1, c: 10}
doSomething(x)
```

and this:

```
declare function doSomething(arg: Example): any
```

that's really not the point here. Consider the following lambda:

```
const example = (i: number, j: number, k: number) => cast<Example>({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
```

to properly set the type without resulting to the identity function I would need to write

```
const example: (i: number, j: number, k: number) => Example = (i, j, k) => ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
```

which is no very DRY

And yes, I can just write

```
function example (i: number, j: number, k: number): Example {
    return {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
}
```

again, not the point

// edit

as @thedude just blew my mind in the comment with the lambda return typeing syntax I did not know about, one more example where I use this casting

```
declare function doSomethingWithArray(arg: Example[]): void

doSomethingWithArray(cast<(Example | boolean)[]>([
    {a: 1, b: 2},
    false,
    {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
]).filter(x => x) as Example[])
```

// edit 2

as it seems I ma terrible at explaining what I want, another example: this generic function solves the filter example-problem

```js
function filterFalse<T>(x: (T | false)[]) {
    return x.filter(x => x) as Exclude<T, false>[]
}

doSomethingWithArray(filterFalse<Example>([
    {a: 1, b: 2},
    false,
    {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} // error
]))
```

but requires defining a specialized function just for this specific task. I am asking if there is a generic way to force a strict type check on a compile-time literal without resulting to a function call. So exactly what `cast<T>` does but without the pointless call in the js output.

Comment: you can also write: `const example = (i: number, j: number, k: number): Example => ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})`

Comment: What's wrong with the last snippet? Why is that not the point? If you write code that doesn't use `any`, then you should _very rarely_ need to do casting like this.

Comment: the point was I wanted a lambda declaration not a function declaration, that is indeed solved with what @thedude wrote in comment above, see edit for another example

Comment: @OtisVallone In the new snippet, you still don't need the `cast` function. The `filter` function can act on any array, so you can give it an array of mixed booleans and `Example` objects. Typescript will already infer that the type of that array is `(boolean | Example)[]`.

Comment: @siride Filter infers an array of union of literal objects (and boolean), not (boolean | Example)[]. Besides for some unknown to me reason even this `doSomethingWithArray([{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}].filter(x => x))` does not fail on the `c`, while without the filter it does.

Comment: @OtisVallone There are many options, but one I just tested was to use `as (boolean | Example)[]` on the array before calling filter. You don't need a `cast` function ever. You just need to use `as`, or follow this code to tell TypeScript that `filter` is a type guard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010737/way-to-tell-typescript-compiler-array-prototype-filter-removes-certain-types-fro/54317362.

Comment: @siride If there a way to do it in a way that gives an error on `c` no existing in `Example` please show me how, I don not see how to achieve this neither with type assertions or type guards or without defining a specialized function just for this

Comment: @OtisVallone: see the update to Alex Wayne's answer at the end.

Comment: @siride I want the compiler to strictly check the object key types, that's the whole point. I know I can just cast the result in thousandth different ways, but that does not change the fact that the compiler will still check the object keys in a weaker manner then normally (accepting keys that where not defined in the interface). Alex Wayne's answer addresses that problem by saying it's a feature.

Comment: @OtisVallone So it looks like your fundamental problem is that `filter()` can take an array of anything, basically. Before you get to filter, you want ensure that the array is already constrained. See this example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChkzk4AuZEAVywCNoAaU8h6ux6YgXwG5ixBAHsQAZzDJQOWmGoAKBiJEE4IAD4Zs+CAEoA2gF1kAXmQG2yQlWQBGZsg7IATL1bl4ecRA9kb1A5O1C6OCNQAzLzERoLCYpLIMMB4kFAQACZm0iCyYAB0yanQCgroetTo0uJomLgEZgB8yGAAnjgQIjDIVQCEpuYA5MqqEOqDevxAA.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a `cast` function in any of these example. I think you may be overthinking this.

---

Let's start here, which is perfectly fine as is.

```
doSomething({a: 2, b: 1, c: 10} as Example)
```

The `as` keyword is still generally typesafe. It lets you cast a value to supertype. In this case `{ a: number, b: number }` is a supertype of `{ a: number, b: number, c: number }`.

For example:

```
const value = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }
const exampleValue: { a: number, b: number } = value // works!
```

And in your first example, if you omit a required property you will have a type error:

```
doSomething({b: 1, c: 10} as Example)
// Property 'a' is missing in type '{ b: number; c: number; }'
// but required in type 'Example'.(2352)
```

So then why does this provide an error?

```
cast<Example>({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}) // error
```

Because when you *create* a value and assign it to a supertype, then you're only reference to that value will be of that supertype. Meaning whatever other properties may exist would be inaccessible. `Example` does not have a `c` property. So typescript assumes that's a mistake, and rightly so.

But in real code, if you passed an object with a, b, and c to a function that only expect a and b, then nothing bad would happen. You've satisfied the constraints, so there's no problem.

---

In this snippet:

```
doSomething(cast<Example>({a: 2, b: 1, c: 10})) // yay, error
```

The cast is pointless. If `doSomething` cares about the type it receives, then it should declare that in its arguments. And if it doesn't care, then there is no need for a cast at all.

---

```
const x: Example = {a: 2, b: 1, c: 10}
doSomething(x)
```

This is basically the same as `as Example` from above.

---

```
declare function doSomething(arg: Example): any
```

This is correct, and exactly what you should be doing. If the function takes a specific type, let it enforce that on its own. You shouldn't need to cast anything if you are assigning it to `any`, since that cast will be lost anyway.

---

```
const example = (i: number, j: number, k: number) =>
  cast<Example>({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
```

If you want a function to return a type, you typically just annotate the return type. The following works fine:

```
const example(i: number, j: number, k: number): Example =>
  ({ a: i, b: j, c: k }) // error, as expected
```

---

> To properly set the type without resulting to the identity function I would need to write:

```
const example: (i: number, j: number, k: number) => Example = (i, j, k) => ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
```

Incorrect, see previous example. One function, type is enforced as expected.

---

Lastly:

```
function example (i: number, j: number, k: number): Example {
    return {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} // error as expected.
}
```

If you want a function that creates and returns an `Example`, this is perfect. It properly alerts you that you have a property that could never be ever be used, and clearly documents the return value.

---

### TLDR:

None of your code snippets should require a `cast<T>()` function at all. I think your best bet is eliminate all occurrences of `any` and then just let Typescript enforce the types. That's what it's there for. The compiler is pretty good, and doesn't *typically* need that much help.

---

### Filtering

Filtering is indeed a weird case in all this. The problem stems from the fact that `filter()` is typed to return the exact same array type that it started with, regardless of what you filter. The common solution is to make the filter callback function a [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Then you could do something like:

```
interface Example {
    a: number
    b: number
}

declare function doSomethingWithArray(arg: Example[]): void

doSomethingWithArray([
    {a: 1, b: 2},
    false,
    {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} // no error because of perfectly safe casting to supertype
].filter((x): x is Example => typeof x !== 'boolean'))
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=12&ssc=55&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChkzk4AuZEAVywCNpTyHq7HmBfY4gEwgI8cKChi0QCMMAD2IZHxkBlGVghgAFqADmAdWCaAglChwAngAoR26hmz4IAbQC6ASmoA3GcD69FKtU0dfSMTcwtHFjJCKmQARgAaZDZkACYuBKjkeDwAZwhM8mQY6kTk6lSkhGoAZi5kAHoGmhlkaCgZKGTBOFp85BkYZBxoGEEwPDNkXLgx5AQ4XOkQbWQwVtzaEagwMxHiZwA6GGA8SCgLC3R3ZHRkYFy0TFwCZABeAD41vYhB2+QAIRvN7IADkDBkMgIcBAoNcrmIQA)

Comment: the first snippet where to explain what I want, the second two where to explain what I don't want, the lambda was the only real example where I use it. I did not know about the lambda syntax where you can specify the return type directly, that solves the lambda example, I added another example where I use this kind of casting.

Comment: See the end of my answer for an update on filtering. You can use a type predicate function to tell typescript that your filtering operation changes the type of the array.

Comment: Look, I made typos in optional object fields too many times to agree with you that it is perfectly safe. Basically you are suggesting that every interface with all fields optional is as good as `Record<string, any>` (well, not exactly because it will still check the value types of the existing keys, but I hope you get the picture). Also if it's such an no error then why is it an error when you just pass a raw array, not the filtered version? The value can be safely casted to the parameter type as its a supertype, yet the compiler still reports an error (as it should).

Comment: `doSomething({b: 1, c: 10} as Example)` is only valid because `c` is not exptected so no type overlaps the other. If you do `doSomething({b: 1} as Example)` would be valid for the compiler