# TypeScript: Filtering an array of number|undefined to include only numbers is not recognized as array of numbers

Tags: typescript

This is my code:

```
type TEntity = Array<{ size?: number }>

const someVar: TEntity =
    //@ts-ignore
    getFromSomewhere()

function isNumber(input: any): input is number {
    return !isNaN(Number(input))
}

const sizes1: number[] = someVar.map(entity => entity.size).filter(size => Number.isInteger(size));
const sizes2: number[] = someVar.map(entity => entity.size).filter(size => isNumber(size));
```

I expected `sizes` and `sizes2` to be automatically of type `number[]` after filtering them, but they weren't. Also specifying types as `: number[]` also is a mistake. I also tried lodash's `isNumber` method, but still no luck.

I don't want to use non-null assertion operator (`!`) as I'm logically filtering everything, and I have linters to prevent usage of non-null assertions.

How can I get the correct type I want?

Here is the link to the TS PlayGround: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogO2AS1FAvFAggJxwQxAB4BvKAZ2QC8IB+ALigQFcBbAIwhygF8A+AFACAxgHsE5YBVGsIANXw5G8JKhAYBULVAD0OgALByAWmQBzBKJwRN2sxGAAxHDIDKMiAHcAFlwgAKAEohADNmBGEUcShkcgA5Nk4cf2QEMGZgRnwEEEDGVPSpWKZErigSWy1rYGYcBCgAQli4-Dj-BI4uFLSMwOCeITEJKUoacgBGRhZOnABtAF0MaVkFHAA6VnwwfwhVNHQ+KF2UUDXRiEC1kOQAG2Au84xDjqS12IBJJAh7ZPO+gG4ROJJBRqBByAAmKalOaLTDkDyrDZbHZ7dQHI5os5gy7XO4PMFPGLxGH+P6Bf5AA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `(size) : size is number` will help you in this case. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010737/way-to-tell-typescript-compiler-array-prototype-filter-removes-certain-types-fro).

```
const sizes1: number[] = someVar.map(entity => entity.size).filter((size) : size is number => Number.isInteger(size));
const sizes2: number[] = someVar.map(entity => entity.size).filter((size) : size is number => isNumber(size));
```

Comment: Thanks. So the thing is that TypeScript can not follow into the filter callback body. Following your answer, changing `.filter(size => isNumber(size))` to simply `.filter(isNumber)` solved my problem too. (as `isNumber` already had the type guard in it). Thanks :thumbsup: but I wished TypeScript did it for me.