# Typescript does not understand filter on undefined values in array of objects

Tags: typescript

I struggle to make typescript understand that I'm already handling the undefined cases of one property (`project`) in this (shortened) example:

```
interface Entry {
    id: number
    project?: Project
    isPublished?: boolean
}

entries
     .filter(entry => !!entry.project)
     .map(entry => ({
           title: entry.project.title
     }))
```

(`entries` is an array of `Entry`s here) and the compiler complains on the line of `entry.project.title` on the `project` property that `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'` even though I have the filter removing the undefined ones. The other optional property is still optional after the filtering, I thus cannot use `Required` interface :/

How can I make TS understand the property is definitely defined in the map function?

Thank you

-- Edit: added another optional property / clarification as response to a suggested answer that would make all properties required

Comment: Duplicate of [TypeScript filter out nulls from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118692/typescript-filter-out-nulls-from-an-array) and [Way to tell TypeScript compiler Array.prototype.filter removes certain types from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010737/way-to-tell-typescript-compiler-array-prototype-filter-removes-certain-types-fro)

Answer (score 5):

You need to define `filter` callback as a [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) and use `Required` type util to make all interface props required:

```js
type Project = {
  title: string
}

interface Entry {
  id: number
  project?: Project
}

type WithProject = Required<Entry>

declare const entries: Entry[]


entries
  .filter((entry): entry is WithProject => !!entry.project)
  .map(entry => ({
    title: entry.project.title
  }))
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nlvd5W)

If you are interested in more type utils please see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype)

Comment: Sorry I did not know it makes a difference if there are multiple optional values in the interface (which there are in my case). I've added this to the original question, but thanks a lot for your suggestion :)

Comment: snoobpoob feel free to use @catgirlkelly solution

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto @captain-yossarian's answer and addressing OP's comment on it, we can make our own utility type to require only a few specific keys:

```
type Project = {
  title: string
}

interface Entry {
  id: number
  project?: Project
}

type SomeAreRequired<T, K extends keyof T> = Required<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>;

type WithProject = SomeAreRequired<Entry, "project">;

declare const entries: Entry[]

entries
  .filter((entry): entry is WithProject => !!entry.project)
  .map(entry => ({
    title: entry.project.title
  }))
```

`SomeAreRequired` **picks** all keys in `T` and makes them required, then adds it to `T` with the `K` keys omitted, effectively making only the selected keys required.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewFYQMbCgXigbwFBRTACWwANhAFxQDOwcxAdgOZ4C+eeTwEcAZgENU0AKKN6IXASjEAJtUYBXALYAjXtLCIU6APzV4yNMHadQkKAGUEyiAEE4EAEoQAjouKPZAHgAqAGigAaSgIAA8eRlkaKABrCBAEPihfAD4sKBd3TwgfGGJUWL9AoNT0gDIoAHllUmLg1LNwaAB1UgALQx0MbGtbB2c3Dy9vMQlAgCItI3QJxrxZNDIBRyhUBEY6UPEGCBpqMbgQAG0AXU4IHeI96QA6PmIyHjgAChfLiQBKag+jmRi2sBOtpjFh0gBCcG-EC3abdT53ZQCMDvHaSTDpF74QiEEjkKjbCSwkHoW54ijSNifT5AA)

Comment: I've been trying to create a generic function out of this but unable to do so. Can you help me with that? @vera.

Comment: @BahrozeAli You can ask another question on Stack Overflow linking this question/answer or contact me on Discord.