# Why the array returning empty spaces

Tags: javascript

It should be returning `9-12,1-4,5-8,9-11` but instead it's returning `9-12,1-4,5-8,9-11,,,,`

```js
var arr = [{
    Sanju: '9-12'
  }, {
    Sanju: '1-4'
  }, {
    Sanju: '5-8'
  }, {
    Sanju: '9-11'
  },
  {
    IRONMAN: '9-12'
  }, {
    VIVEGAM: '1-4'
  }, {
    VIVEGAM: '5-8'
  }, {
    VIVEGAM: '9-11'
  }
];

var b = Array.from(arr, x => x.Sanju);
document.write(b);
document.write(Array.isArray(b));
```

Comment: coz there is no `Sanju` property on some of the objects

Comment: so how to get rid of this **,** and get only **Sanju Object** objects

Comment: use `arr.filter(i=> i.Sanju);`. well, I've added that as an answer too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since not all values in arr contains `Sanju`, some of the values will give you undefined when you return `x.Sanju` You can use filter to remove those like

```js
var arr = [{Sanju: '9-12'},{Sanju: '1-4'}, {Sanju: '5-8'},{Sanju: '9-11'},
  {IRONMAN: '9-12'},{VIVEGAM: '1-4'}, {VIVEGAM: '5-8'},{VIVEGAM: '9-11'}
];
 
 var b= Array.from(arr, x => x.Sanju).filter(Boolean);
    document.write(b);
    document.write(Array.isArray(b));
```

Check [Removing undefined values from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607451/removing-undefined-values-from-array) for more details on how `.filter(Boolean)` works

Answer (score 4):

*It should be returning 9-12,1-4,5-8,9-11 but instead it's returning 9-12,1-4,5-8,9-11,,,,*

Coz there is no `Sanju` property on some of the objects. You should first filter you array and then do the rest

```js
var arr = [{
    Sanju: '9-12'
  }, {
    Sanju: '1-4'
  }, {
    Sanju: '5-8'
  }, {
    Sanju: '9-11'
  },
  {
    IRONMAN: '9-12'
  }, {
    VIVEGAM: '1-4'
  }, {
    VIVEGAM: '5-8'
  }, {
    VIVEGAM: '9-11'
  }
];

var o = arr.filter(i=> i.Sanju);

var b = Array.from(o, x => x.Sanju);
document.write(b);
 
document.write(Array.isArray(b));
```