# At which point does Array​.prototype​.filter() check for falsy values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I stumbled upon [this great function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46125317/7910454) to remove [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) from an array:

```
let other = array.filter(item => item);
```

But I don't understand how this can work. As far as I understand the explanation of [Array​.prototype​.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) found on the MDN:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The following code should be the same thing as the one found above (and it does provide the same output):

```
function foo(item) {
  return item;
}

let other = array.filter(foo);
```

But `foo()` just returns all the falsy values as you can see in the snippet below (as expected). **When does the filtering take place if the falsy values DO pass the *provided function*?**

```js
let array = ['foo', undefined, false, 'bar'];

function foo(item) {
  return item;
}

array.forEach(item => console.log(foo(item)));
```

**EDIT:** There has been some misunderstanding about my question: I am aware that I am not using `filter()` in the snippet. This is because its only purpose is to show that all the values *pass* the `foo()`-function which, at the time, seemed like a contradiction to: *[...] all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.*

Looking at the Polyfill and the Description I now understand why it works the way it does. Thank you, @adiga. I did not fully understand *[...] returns a value that coerces to true* since English is not my first language but I guess it means something along the lines of *[...] returns only the truthy values*.

Comment: it checks the returned value and if truthy, then the element passes.

Comment: It's clearly mentioned in the [Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Description) of `Array.prototype.filter`: "filter() calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, and constructs a new array of all the values **for which callback returns a value that coerces to true**"

Comment: @Seblor That is on purpose. It is showing that `foo()` doesn't change the values at all.

Comment: Did you checked the Polyfill of `filter` on same page as referenced in question - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill

Comment: @MiXT4PE I actually misunderstood what you misunderstood. Your `foo` function, in itself, does literally nothing. However, sending it as parameter to the `filter` function filters the falsy values.

Comment: _But foo() just returns all the falsy values as you can see in the snippet below (as expected)._ ... No! In your snippet, you are using **forEach**, you're **NOT** filtering! **The foo callback acts just as expected, just like the lambda!** https://jsfiddle.net/12cymk3j/ . Coercing in lambdas and vanilla functions is identical, there is nothing different.

Comment: I don't see that you used 'filter' function in your code snippet

Comment: If you really want to understand "how it works", just check [the polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill)

Comment: *"all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function"* means just all elements for which the provided function returns a truthy value. That's what everybody here is trying to tell you!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Oh, I guess I just didn't understand that sentence then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but `filter` returns only the values for which the filter callback returns a value that gets coerced to `true` (ie non-falsy).

That's why filtering out falsy values simply requires the filter function to return the value itself.

(The callback could also explicitly return a boolean with `!!value`, which would do the same thing.)

Comment: The example he provided doesn't use filter, but **forEach**. Filtering works in both examples as expected, there is **nothing** wrong using a function reference as a function instead of a lambda, the result will be the same due to the return value that is coerced in both cases. https://jsfiddle.net/12cymk3j/