# how to skip undefined value from array to prevent unnecessary element in jsx

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux

I want to display array values using map in jsx, but don't want to create element for undefined value. here in below example, mainArray has multiple subarrays, and in last array, last element is undefined. and unnecessary list is getting created for undefined value.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
const d=['link1','link2','link3','link4','link5'];
const mainArr=[];
  var a=[];
  var b=[];
  var c=[];
  for(var i=0;i<d.length;i=i+3){
    a.push(d[i]);
    b.push(d[i+1]);
    c.push(d[i+2]);
   }
  mainArr.push(a,b,c);
   
  
  return (
    <div>
      {
      mainArr.map((link,ind) => {
       return (
          <div>
            <ul>
            {/* <div>{ind}</div> */}
            {
              link.map(item=> {
                return(
                  <li>{item}</li>
                )
              })
            }
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
  </div>
  );
  }
```

Comment: have you thought about filtering the array before using it? Remove all the undefined elements and then use it

Comment: Either the suggestion above or you can do a check to see if item exists. `{item && <li>{item}</li>`

Comment: `yourArray.filter(Boolean).map` should do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing undefined values from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607451/removing-undefined-values-from-array)

Comment: item && <li>{item}</li>, this solution is working fine