# Sorting objects but maintaining tied values

Tags: jquery, sorting, duplicates

I have an array of objects that need to be sorted into a list but I'd like to group tied values. The array is essentially:

```
var sorted = [
    {
        section:"Red",
        score:12
    },
    {
        section:"Green",
        score:12
    },
    {
        section:"Blue",
        score:9
    },
...
]
```

And the result I am aiming for would be to output something along the lines of `Your first choices are Red and Green, your second choice is Blue, your third choices are...`

I've sorted the main array already to sort the objects in an ascending order, but don't really know how to address the objects that have the same score.

I have been trying to get this to work https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sort-the-array-and-group-all-the-identical-duplicate-numbers-into-their-separate-subarray-in-javascript but I can't quite figure it out to adapt to my situation. This doesn't quite work but I am getting close. It seems to be missing the first result...

```js
var sorted = [
    {
        section:"Red",
        score:12
    },
    {
        section:"Green",
        score:12
    },
    {
        section:"Blue",
        score:9
    },
    {
        section:"Yellow",
        score:8
    },
    {
        section:"Grey",
        score:6
    },
    {
        section:"Black",
        score:6
    }
]
const sortAndGroup = (sorted = []) => {
   let result = [];
   let groupArray = [];
   for (let i = 1; i < sorted.length; i++) {
      if (sorted[i - 1].score !== sorted[i].score) {
         groupArray = [];
         result.push(groupArray);
      };
      groupArray.push(sorted[i].section + ", " + sorted[i].score);
   };
   return result;
};
console.log(sortAndGroup(sorted));
```

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: sorry added what I am working on so far.

Comment: First group all the elements by score, then sort this array by score. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523003/group-by-array-and-add-field-and-sub-array-in-main-array for the grouping part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) we can combine the grouping with the sorting.

If we use the number `score` as index of our result array from `reduce()`, we only need to [remove the `undefined`'s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607451/removing-undefined-values-from-array) from the array to end up with a sorted list of objects

```js
var data = [
    { section:"Blue",   score:9  },
    { section:"Yellow", score:8  }, 
    { section:"Red",    score:12 },
    { section:"Purple", score: 1 },
    { section:"Green",  score:12 },
    { section:"Grey",   score:6  },
    { section:"Black",  score:6  }
]

let result = data.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (!a[c.score]) a[c.score] = { score: c.score, options: [ ]};
    a[c.score].options.push(c.section)
    return a
}, []).filter(Boolean);

result.forEach(({ score, options }, i) => {
    console.log(`${i + 1} --> Score: ${score}\tOptions: ${options.join(', ')}`); 
});
```

```
1 --> Score: 1  Options: Purple
2 --> Score: 6  Options: Grey, Black
3 --> Score: 8  Options: Yellow
4 --> Score: 9  Options: Blue
5 --> Score: 12 Options: Red, Green
```

Comment: I've had some great success with this so far. I am now trying to reverse the order as I am trying to have it ascending... is there a way to do that with reduce?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, add a `.reverse()` behind `.filter(Boolean)`. (On mobile now, otherwise I'd add a snippet ;) )

Comment: AMAZING. Oh man I was struggling with this. Thank you so much. I'm off to read more about .reduce but I've got it working now and can continue on! Really appreciate the help.